# Finding ways to split list or arrays

Tags: python

I have a list of values like below, need to split it using `","` and create a output column like below.

Input:

```
"date=202101;date=202102;date=202103;date=202104;date=202105;date=202105;,date=202208;date=202209;"
```

Output:

```
date=202101;date=202102;date=202103;date=202104;date=202105;date=202105
date=202208;date=202209
```

Following is the code I have tried, but its giving no output.

```
    in_list = 
        "date=202101;date=202102;date=202103;date=202104;date=202105;date=202105;,date=202208;date=202209;"
    out_list = []
    out_list.append(in_list.split(","))
    print(out_list)
```

Already tried with mentioned code using split but not working.

Comment: What do you mean "but its giving no output"?  `print(out_list)` certainly should print _something_...

Comment: It prints `[['date=202101;date=202102;date=202103;date=202104;date=202105;date=202105;', 'date=202208;date=202209;']]` for me

Comment: It's not clear why you're appending to `out_list` instead of just assigning it.

Comment: Your output is identical to your input.  `print(in_list)` should do what you ask, so what you ask is probably not what you want.  Since there are no commas, you don't want to split on commas.  You could split on `';'`.

Comment: There's only one comma in your string (before the second to last date), is this a typo or is the original like that? Make sure you are showing the data as it is.

Comment: I want to split on comma and output should like array below.

Comment: date=202101;date=202102;date=202103;date=202104;date=202105;date=202105
date=202208;date=202209

Comment: did you want to `extend()` rather than `append()`?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you just want to replace comma with space:

```py
s = "date=202101;date=202102;date=202103;date=202104;date=202105;date=202105;,date=202208;date=202209;"
print(s.replace(',', '\n'))
```

Or this if you want to split:

```py
for item in s.split(','):
    print(item)
```

Output (both cases):

```
date=202101;date=202102;date=202103;date=202104;date=202105;date=202105;
date=202208;date=202209;
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should check the return value of the function split, it's not a string it's a list.

```py
in_list = "date=202101;date=202102;date=202103;date=202104;date=202105;date=202105;,date=202208;date=202209;"

#convert string to list by splitting at the delimiter
out_list = in_list.split(',')

#if you want to pretty print it 
print("".join(out_list))
```

Comment: I am receiving string of values , want to put in  a list as one column array. in_list coming as First time : "date=202101", second time :  "date=202101;date=202102;date=202103;date=202104;date=202105;date=202105;,date=202208;date=202209;"

Comment: out should should be like:

Comment: date=202101;
date=202101;date=202102;date=202103;date=202104;date=202105;date=202105;
date=202208;date=2022;

Comment: you split at the coma, save the new value to a list eg : out
then out contains two elements ["date=202101;date=202102;date=202103;date=202104;date=202105;date=202105;", "date=202208;date=202209;"]
if you want to print them you join them with "".join(out)